# Seg fault, need help reading a core dump

Tags: c++, adt, coredump

I have an error with an assignment, of which I get a seg fault, that when reading the core dump gives this:

```
#0  0xb781eb27 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

This is the code snippet I believe it is referring to.

```
bool flightmap::GetNextCity(int& index, int& nextCity){
    bool success = false;
    flightRec tmp, tmp2;
    for (int i = nextCity; (!success) && (i < size); i++)
    {//if Citytmp goes over size, we never found it
        tmp.DestinationCity = GetCityName(i);
        tmp2 = map[index].Retrieve(tmp,success);
    }//end for loop
    if (success)
    {
        nextCity = GetCityNumber(tmp2.DestinationCity);
    }//end if
    return success;
}
```

Here is the Retrieve function:

```
flightRec sortedListClass::Retrieve(flightRec& input, bool& success) const{
    nodeptr curr;
    flightRec tmp;
    curr = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {//If the list is empty
        std::cout << "List empty, operation not preformed" << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    /*LINE 167*/ while ((curr!=NULL)&&(!(curr->DestinationCity==input.DestinationCity))) //<- THIS IS LINE 167
    {//Here we first check if curr points to NULL, then we see if DesinationCity and Origin are not yet found.
        curr=curr->ptr;
    }
    if ((curr->DestinationCity==input.DestinationCity))
    {//If we found it, then let's return it...
        tmp.DestinationCity=curr->DestinationCity;
        //tmp.Origin=curr->Origin;
        tmp.flightnumber=curr->flightnumber;
        tmp.cost=curr->cost;
        success = true;
        return tmp;
    }
    else //We didn't and then...damn.
    {
        //std::cout << "Can't find flight to " << input.DestinationCity << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
}
```

flightRec:

```
struct flightRec{
    std::string Origin;
    int flightnumber;
    float cost;
    std::string DestinationCity;
    bool operator <(const flightRec& rhs) const;
    bool operator ==(const flightRec& rhs) const;
    flightRec* ptr;
};
typedef flightRec* nodeptr;
```

flightMap.h

```
#ifndef FLIGHTMAP_H
#define FLIGHTMAP_H
#include "sortedListClass.h"
#include "stackClass.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

class flightmap {
public:
    flightmap();
    flightmap(const flightmap& orig);
    virtual ~flightmap();
    void readcities (std::ifstream& in);
    void readflights (std::ifstream& in);
    void display ();
    void isPath (int& in, int& out);
    void MarkVisited (int& index);
    bool IsVisited (int& index);
    void UnvisitAll ();
    bool GetNextCity (int& index, int& nextCity);
    int GetCityNumber(std::string& city);
    std::string GetCityName(int& index);
private:
    int size;
    sortedListClass* map;
    std::string* origin;
    bool* visited;
};

#endif
```

After typing bt into gdb this is what the output was:

```
#0  0xb7f4eb27 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0804a407 in std::operator==<char> (__lhs=..., __rhs=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/basic_string.h:2345
#2  0x0804ab32 in sortedListClass::Retrieve (this=0x8053468, input=..., success=@0xbffff0a3) at sortedListClass.cpp:167
#3  0x0804a1ff in flightmap::GetNextCity (this=0xbffff4dc, index=@0xbffff108, nextCity=@0xbffff104) at flightMap.cpp:197
#4  0x08049ba7 in flightmap::isPath (this=0xbffff4dc, in=@0xbffff164, out=@0xbffff160) at flightMap.cpp:110
#5  0x08049314 in FindPath (datafile=..., map=...) at ola6.cpp:51
#6  0x08049190 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff5b4) at ola6.cpp:35
```

Comment: You'll have to post the full backtrace.  #0 only tells you the function where the problem was triggered, but it doesn't tell you how it got there.  You need to follow it back until you reach a line in your source file, and that will tell you which line in your code causes the problem.  I don't think it could be the snippet you posted.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bt` is correct for a backtrace.  You can see there the error starts in `sortedListClass::Retrieve` line 167.  The next entry in the backtrace (working back up to #0) is for operator ==, which means the == on line 167 is the cause of the crash.

There are a few == calls in the code you posted, so if you can edit your post and indicate which line is line 167 we can diagnose further.

Update after line number was added:

This is just a guess, but it's possible you have forgotten to set the `ptr` member to NULL at some point earlier in the program, so that in that loop around line 167-168 `curr` eventually points at a random memory location, causing the crash.  It's also possible that the object at that memory location has since been freed, but `ptr` hasn't been updated and is pointing at the now deleted object.  Check your code closely where you allocate new `flightRec` objects and make sure you are always setting `ptr` correctly.

Comment: Edited but here is line if ((curr != NULL) && (curr->DestinationCity==input.DestinationCity))

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `size` declared/defined in your code?

It looks like you're somehow ending up with that being called as the std::basic_string `size` method.

Comment: size is declared as an int in the flightmap.h under the private data section

Comment: please post flightmap.h. In addition, you're going to have a problem if `head` is NULL in `Retrieve` as you assign it to `curr`,  then access `curr->DestinationCity` regardless if your check for null failed or not. What would also help is if you posted the entire stack trace.

Comment: I am not sure how to retrieve the stack in gdb. I think I figured it out. Nope